# Mac OS X custom keyboard shortcuts

Tags: snow-leopard, keyboard

Whenever I set a custom keyboard shortcut in Mac OS X (10.6.8) for a menu item, I cannot use it until I open its menu by clicking on it at least once. This happens every time I launch an app and affects services too.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you using the Keyboard preference pane to set these shortcuts? Are you sure they don't collide with another shortcut defines somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I do. And shortcuts don't collide with other shortcuts...

Comment: That's odd; I've never seen that happen. Hopefully someone who has will have an answer.

Comment: Try this test: make a new service using Automator, then assign it a shortcut...

Comment: I set a keystroke for the service, then opened the Services menu it one app (to make sure it was assigned), ran it there via the keystroke, then went to a different app and ran it (successfully) via the keystroke there without opening the menu in that app.

Comment: I have had this problem “forever” myself. It appears to be gone in one of the latest Lion updates.

Comment: I'm pretty happy to know I won't have this bug anymore when I'll upgrade to ML. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @egon1984 Harald didn't mention ML.

Comment: Harald mentioned Lion, and ML is a Lion update.

Comment: I think @HaraldHanche-Olsen meant 10.7.x. I'm still running into the same issue on 10.7.4 though.

Comment: Yes, I meant 10.7.x. But if others are still seeing it on 10.7.4, then it may not have been the upgrade that cured it for me.

Comment: So, which upgrade cured it for you?